# Getting httpContext is null error while trying to access dbcontext

Tags: structuremap, httpcontext, dbcontext

We have a MVC 4 project and using Structure Map as an IoC framework. When we make an async call to the service class that using DbContext it throws an exception:

```
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext

Exception Details: System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: httpContext
```

Once it has thrown this:

```
The operation cannot be completed because the DbContext has been disposed.
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: How are you injecting your `DbContext` into the container?